# How to choose which label will be more wide using autolayout?

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

I'am trying to do simple app in Swift. After typing login and password, it should show the username and company. Below buttons, i have two labels called `Name` and `Company`, and on the right of them two labels to show actual user name and his company. I want the labels `Name` and `Company` to be just wide enough, to show this text. The labels for actual user name and company should be much wider. When i use autolayout to connect them, the first labels are much wider, than others. How can I change that?

Here is photo of this layout:
[image: Photo showing layout of application]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your storyboard, click on your `Name` and `Company` labels and set their `Horizontal Content Hugging Priority` (in the Size Inspector) to a value higher than the label that should be wider.

[image]

Comment: You are very welcome :) Welcome to Stack Overflow! Don't forget to mark the answer as "accepted" by clicking the checkmark on the left ;)